# MongoDB dup key: { : null }

Tags: mongodb

I don't have a lot of MongoDB experience, and I'm running into the following with an mLab instance I have:

`E11000 duplicate key error index: development.users.$key_1 dup key: { : null } MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: development.users.$key_1 dup key: { : null }`

I've tried sorting by the `key` field, looking for a `null` key, and am not sure how I should go about finding the duplicate `null` key.  What makes this difficult is that I'm not even sure what to search Google or stack overflow for to work through this.  Any help would be appreciated, and below is the full error:

```
Mongoose model 'index-single-done' event fired on 'Family' for index:
Object {key: 1}

With error:
    E11000 duplicate key error index: development.users.$key_1 dup key: { : null } MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: 
development.users.$key_1 dup key: { : null }
at Function.MongoError.create (/Users/myUserName/development/projectName/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
at /Users/myUserName/development/projectName/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:497:72
at authenticateStragglers (/Users/myUserName/development/projectName/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:443:16)
at Connection.messageHandler (/Users/myUserName/development/projectName/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:477:5)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/myUserName/development/projectName/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:333:22)
at Socket.emit (events.js:180:13)
at Socket.emit (domain.js:422:20)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:274:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:261:11)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:218:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:581:20)
Mongoose model 'index' event fired on 'Family' with error:
E11000 duplicate key error index: development.users.$key_1 dup key: { : null } MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: development.users.$key_1 dup key: { : null }
at Function.MongoError.create (/Users/myUserName/development/projectName/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
at /Users/myUserName/development/projectName/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:497:72
at authenticateStragglers (/Users/myUserName/development/projectName/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:443:16)
at Connection.messageHandler (/Users/myUserName/development/projectName/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:477:5)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/myUserName/development/projectName/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:333:22)
at Socket.emit (events.js:180:13)
at Socket.emit (domain.js:422:20)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:274:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:261:11)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:218:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:581:20)
```

Answer (score 4):

I encountered with the same issue

I have tried different techniques either looking the database validations or the database values but nothing found invalid that could produce this error.

finally deleted the collections and problem solved. Though it is not the good solution but in testing phase it is OK.

Comment: This worked for me too! Good find, hope no one has to go through this in production! :D

Comment: If you are using Atlas, you can remove the `unique` property in the offending field, and then drop the indexes in Atlas, without dropping the collection.

Answer (score 2):

`duplicate key error index: development.users.$key_1 dup key: { : null }`

This means that your `key` field is set to accept only unique values and there is already one record with `key` having `null` value and you cannot insert another document with `key` as `null`. It is similar to having primary key in SQL databases.

Check your mongoose schema as it looks like you are using mongoose.

Most likely:

1. while saving a record you're not passing key
2. If you're passing key, it's value is null

Comment: Thanks @Raj Kumar, it definitely looks like that's the case.  What I'd like to do now is find the two records with a null value in the 'key' field, but I can't seem to get a search to do anything. { 'key': null } doesn't return anything.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There will not be 2 records having key value as null in your case. Can you post your full code that you are using to search it ?

Comment: I have the same error, also no null keys in the collection :/

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have a collection with a field with unique indexing set to true. And then you add a document in that collection with that unique indexed field missing in the document. Then the document gets inserted and the indexes of that collection are updated with a null value for this document's index.

Thereafter when you try to add more documents with this field missing into the same collection, the earlier null value and the new document's null value collide and you get the `dup key: { <KEY>: null }` error.

To avoid this, you can set the index to be a sparse index. Sparse indexes will store the data to index only if there is a value available (other than null), else that field won't be indexed.

PS: If you are encountering this error and then added sparse and still you get the same error, then you might want to drop the existing indexes first and then reindex to get rid of the old indexed values.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, I had the same problem and it originated from a typo between the field name in the collection and the field name in the index.
I know, stupid mistake, but confusing to find.

- field name in collection was "postType"
- field name in index was {post_type: 1}

Hope it helps anyone.

Answer (score 1):

First, you must check your indices using command: **db.collection.getIndices()**

Second, if you discover that the error index exists, you may consider dropping it using the command: **db.collection.dropIndex("key_id")**